# node.js not importing css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm creating an example of `node.js` for uploading files and store form.
The problem is my `css` and `js` files not work when I access from `localhost` in any port. I use port 3000, when I open the file `index.html` in browser is ok, but when I follow `localhost:3000` or any port, the port isn't the problem and `css` files do not work. So my codes are:

The `HTML`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Video Uploader</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/formstorage.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form>

<div class="cont fl">
 <h1>File's Uploader:</h1>

 <div class="fl form">
 <div>
 <h1>
 Your Name:
 </h1>
 
 <input type="text" class="inps" id="nome">
 
 </div>
 <div>
 <h1>
 e-mail:
 </h1>
 
 <input type="text" class="inps" id="email">
 
 </div>
 <div class="bt">
  <div class="fl">
   <input type="button" value="Record" id="rec">
  </div> 
  <div class="fr">
   <input type="button" value="Upload" id="file">
  </div>
 </div>

 
 <input type="button" value="Confirm" id="sub">

 </div>
<!-- fim do formulario -->

<div class=" fr" id="contentv">
</div>

</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `js` for open server:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Just remove `public` part from style and script path.

Comment: this is a folder name, i have public, inside of public folder have css and javascript folders. But I gonna try remove the folders of inside public folder.

Comment: still does not work.

Comment: Try to add `/` at beginning of the paths.

Comment: I suggest you not to use node js as your entire web server.

Comment: @RamonLago Please have a look at developer console or similar stuff in the browser. Check what error messages are.

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'public' in path.
cf) `/css/style.css`

Cause of this line (`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'PATH')));`), 
the `PATH/FILE`'s `absolute URL` is just `/FILE`.

Comment: I do this but still not working.. I add this line "app.use[...]" and insert '/'...

Comment: just remove `public` in your html files.
like this.
`<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/formstorage.js"></script>`
`<script src="/javascript/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: and DO NOT modify `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: I do this but still isn'it work.. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

tanks for help me.
I do know but I modify this code several times, and not work..
Now what I do:
I create de folder public/css/style.css and add the line app.use() with 'public' like 김재원 say in my Node file. And in link of html I write "/css/style.css".
Before still isn't work. I try and try and try but isn't work.
NOW is working... I do know what's happening here, but the same thing now is working lol.